# Problema con composer y symfony/var-dumper:3.4 en Symfony2. ¿Puedo instalar la versión 4.* de var dumper?

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony, composer

Estoy instalando un proyecto de Symfony2 pero al intentar correr el comando `composer install` me sale un error en particular.

Problem 1

```
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.49
- don't install symfony/var-dumper v3.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.49
- don't install symfony/var-dumper v3.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.49
```

(Continúa la lista...)

```
- don't install symfony/var-dumper v3.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.49
- Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.7.49 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.7.49].
- Installation request for symfony/var-dumper ^3.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
```

Intenté instalar symfony/symfony:2.7.49 y symfony/var-dumper:3.4.0 por separado pero vienen los mismos mensajes. No estoy seguro porque podría ser este problema, podría intentar instalar la version 4 de var-dumper pero no se si es compatible con Symfony2, no quisiera tener problemas con el proyecto más adelante por esta razón.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda! :)

EDITO: A petición agrego el composer.json (al menos la parte de require), gracias por sus respuestas!

```
"require": {
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.49",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "ci/restclientbundle": "^1.0",
        "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.7.0.9",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "~1.1",
        "jms/twig-js": "dev-master",
        "jms/twig-js-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^3.4"
    },
```

EDITO2: Yo me voy a incorporar al proyecto, el equipo actual tiene esa configuración actualmente por lo que me parece raro que haya errores, si ellos están desarrollando así, tambien debería poder correrlo.

Comment: sin ver el composer.json que tienes es un poco dificil. Puedes echar un vistazo a `https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/var-dumper#v3.4.0` para ver si alguna de las dependencias de la libreria es la que te da el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba relacionado con la versión de php y mongodb que tenia instalados en mi ordenador. Lo resolví creando contenedores en Docker con docker-compose para no pelearme con las versiones directamente en la computadora.

Estaba usando en mi pc php7.2 y Mongo4, necesitaba las versiones php5.6 y Mongo3

Answer (score 0):

revisando el packagist de [var_dumper](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/var-dumper#v2.8.50), deberías instalar la versión 2.8 que es la que es compatible con symfony2.8, si esta también presenta problemas, intenta instalar un proyecto de ceros con la versión de symfony que estás usando

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "2.8.*"
```

solo cambia el 2.8 por la versión que tienes y revisa que var_dumper se instala, con esto te aseguras tener la versión compatible a tu proyecto.

Espero te sirva la ayuda!